# ClassCastException when placing RadioGroupFieldEditor in FormLayout

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am a newbie to SWT GUI development. I am using SWT for developing Eclipse plug-ins. Basically, I wanted two radio option groups and some textboxes beneath the second radio option group; something like below.

```
    Heading1
    . A radio button
    . B radio button
    Heading2
    . C radio button
    . D radio button
    Textbox1 Textbox2 Textbox3
```

**Since I needed those text boxes relative to each other,I used FormLayout**. But it gives me exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData*

But I haven't used `GridData`. 
Exception occurs at line 129.
I am unable to add Textbox2 relative to Textbox1.My code is below.

```
        Shell sh = new Shell(parent_shell,SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL | SWT.TRAIL | SWT.CASCADE);
        System.out.println("execute");
        FormLayout fL = new FormLayout();
        sh.setLayout(fL);
        sh.setText("Configure");

        sh.setSize(330,300);
        sh.setActive();

        Composite composite = new Composite( sh, SWT.NONE );
         GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
         layout.marginWidth = 0;
         layout.marginHeight = 0;
         composite.setLayout( layout );

         FormData fd = new FormData(); //line 100
         fd.top = new FormAttachment(0,0);//line 101
         fd.left = new FormAttachment(0,0);//line 102
         //fd.right = new FormAttachment(26);//line 103
         //fd.bottom = new FormAttachment(10);//line 104
         composite.setLayoutData( fd );

         RadioGroupFieldEditor rgfe = new RadioGroupFieldEditor("User Choice",
                 "Heading1", 1, new String[][]{
             {"A radio button","a"},{"B radio button","b"}
         }, composite,false);

         RadioGroupFieldEditor rgfe1 = new RadioGroupFieldEditor("User Choice1",
                 "Heading2", 1, new String[][]{
             {"C radio button","c"},{"D radio button","d"}
         }, composite,false);



         Text ol = new Text(composite,SWT.READ_ONLY);
            ol.setText("Output Location");
            ol.setEnabled(false);

//              FormData fd1 = new FormData();
//              fd.top = new FormAttachment(fd);
//              fd.left = new FormAttachment(1);
//              fd.right = new FormAttachment(26);
//              fd.bottom = new FormAttachment(10);
//              ol.pack();
//              ol.setLayoutData(fd1); //line 129 --> exception occurs




         while (!sh.isDisposed()) {
              if (!parent_display.readAndDispatch()) {
                  parent_display.sleep();
              }
            }

    }
```

Comment: The `RadioGroupFieldEditor` assumes that its parent has a `GridLayout` set. I suggest you embed the `RadioGroupFieldEditor` in a separate Composite that has a GridLayout set.

Comment: Field Editor classes expect to be used in a `FieldEditorPreferencePage` preference page. You will struggle to get them to work properly anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The `RadioGroupFieldEditor` assumes that its parent has a `GridLayout` set.

I suggest you embed the `RadioGroupFieldEditor` in a separate `Composite` that has a `GridLayout` set. Then you can attach FormData to the Composite to control its layout.

For example:

```java
Composite composite = new Composite( sh, SWT.NONE );
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
layout.marginWidth = 0;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
composite.setLayout( layout );
FormData compositeFormData = new FormData();
...
composite.setLayoutData( compositeFormData );
RadioGroupFieldEditor fieldEditor = new RadioGroupFieldEditor( ..., composite, ... );
```

Comment: But i want those textboxes relative to each other which I guess is possible only through FormLayout.If I use GridLayout then yet again the same exception would occur,isn't it?

Comment: Please try the suggested solution.

Comment: I used composite instead of sh in RadioGroupFieldEditior but it gives the same exception at ol.setLayoutData(fd);

Comment: Which layout did you set for the composite?